# MsBuild: Flattening of nested ItemGroup with variable number of metadata

Tags: msbuild, metadata, itemgroup

Assume the following ItemGroup structure:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <BinaryFiles Include="C:\">
    <Binary>a.dll</Binary>
    <Binary>b.dll</Binary>
  </BinaryFiles>
  <BinaryFiles Include="D:\">
    <Binary>my.ddl</Binary>
  </BinaryFiles>
</ItemGroup>
```

I need to flatten this to a string like this:

```
C:\a.dll;C:\b.dll;D:\my.dll
```

How would I do that? If it's not possible, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A metadata value can have only one value. Multiple definitions and updates will override the value, so the `"C:\"` item will only have `b.dll` as `Binary` metadata.

If there is only one element in the metadata then `@(BinaryFiles->'%(Identity)%(Binary)')` would yield the result you wanted.

However, since you are using file based logic, you are better off using a `BinaryFiles` item for each item:

```
<BinaryFiles Include="C:\*.dll" />
<BinaryFiles Include="D:\*.dll" />
```

This will scan for all the dll files. You can even use `D:\**\*.dll` to scan recursively. Then you can use `@(BinaryFiles->'%(FullPath')` to get the list of all absolute paths.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to avoid to repeat the common path every time. Is there a better way which lets me specify the path once for a bunch of files, and them list the files in a variable number of tags?

Comment: Do you want to specify them all? the above example would search for files matching the pattern (`*.dll`)

Comment: I want to selectively add specific files, not all files matching a pattern. There can be a lot more DLL files in a directory than I want to specify.